# How to identify particular descendant element found under first-or-second descendant of another element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest to identify the MFENCED, which is having MFRAC as descendant of MSUB or not.

Here some scenarios mentioned as below to stretch the MFENCED (inserting one attribute):

- If MFRAC found and which is not under MSUB, then attribute STRETCH
  required for MFENCED.
- If MFRAC found as descendant to MFENCED and
  under FIRST-CHILD-DESCENDANT of MSUB, then STRETCH required.
- In third MATH from input xml, 2nd MFENCED required STRETCH, even that MFRAC descendant of 2nd child descendant of MSUB, but with within that MFENCED, MFRAC is not having MSUB as its ancestor.

**Newly added further explanations:**

If `MFENCED` under (descendant from (*this*) present MFENCED) any `MFRAC` found, then that MFENCED can stretch, where MFENCE/ancestor should not, because, with respect to main MFENCE, FRAC found under *sub*s 2nd child-descendant. If not clear, i will give further explanations.

**Input XML:**

```
<article>

<math>
    <mrow>
        <mfenced open="(" close=")">
            <!--stretch required -->
            <mrow>
                <mrow><mn>99999</mn></mrow>
                    <mrow>
                            <mrow><mn>9999</mn></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mfenced open="(" close=")">
                                    <!--stretch required -->
                                    <mrow>
                                        <mfrac><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi></mfrac>
                                    </mrow>
                                </mfenced>
                            </mrow>
                    </mrow>
                </mrow>
        </mfenced>
    </mrow>
</math>

<math>
    <mrow>
        <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--Stretch  required, bcs descendant Frac, found as first child of msub, if descendant mfrac, found under (descendant) second child of MSUB, then no need to stretch-->
            <mrow>
                <mrow><mn>99999</mn></mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <msub>
                            <mrow>
                                <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--Stretch required, because under this mfen, 'mfrac' found under first child of 'msub' -->
                                    <mrow>
                                        <mfrac><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi></mfrac>
                                    </mrow>
                                </mfenced>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow><mn>9999</mn></mrow>
                        </msub>
                    </mrow>
                </mrow>
        </mfenced>
    </mrow>
</math>


<math>
    <mrow>
        <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!-- this mfence, no need to stretch, because, descendant MFRAC found under second child-descendant of MSUB -->
            <mrow>
                <mrow><mn>99999</mn></mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <msub>
                            <mrow><mn>9999</mn></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--Stretch required, because under this mfen, 'mfrac' found (even MFRAC under 2nd child-descendant of MSUB, but under existing MFENCE, MFRAC is not having ancestor MSUB -->
                                    <mrow>
                                        <mfrac><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi></mfrac>
                                    </mrow>
                                </mfenced>
                            </mrow>
                        </msub>
                    </mrow>
                </mrow>
        </mfenced>
    </mrow>
</math>
</article>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mfenced">
    <xsl:variable name="varFrac">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::mfenced">
            <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[name()='mfrac']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when  test="not(ancestor::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')]
                        [generate-id(ancestor::mmlmfenced[1])=generate-id(current()/ancestor::mmlmfenced[1])])">Yes2</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when  test="(ancestor-or-self::*/parent::*[not(preceding-sibling::*)]/parent::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')]
                        [generate-id(ancestor::mmlmfenced[1])=generate-id(current()/ancestor::mmlmfenced[1])])">Yes21</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[name()='mfrac']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when  test="not(ancestor::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')])">Yes1a</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when  test="(ancestor-or-self::*/parent::*[not(preceding-sibling::*)]/parent::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')])">Yes11a</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($varFrac, 'Yes')">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="stretchy">true</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required result:**

```
<article>
<math>
  <mrow>
     <mfenced open="(" close=")" stretchy="true">
          <mrow>
           <mrow>
              <mn>99999</mn>
           </mrow>
           <mrow>
              <mrow>
                 <mn>9999</mn>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                 <mfenced open="(" close=")" stretchy="true">
                    <mrow>
                       <mfrac>
                          <mi>a</mi>
                          <mi>b</mi>
                       </mfrac>
                    </mrow>
                 </mfenced>
              </mrow>
           </mrow>
        </mrow>
     </mfenced>
  </mrow>
</math>

<math>
  <mrow>
     <mfenced open="(" close=")" stretchy="true">
        <mrow>
           <mrow>
              <mn>99999</mn>
           </mrow>
           <mrow>
              <msub>
                 <mrow>
                    <mfenced open="(" close=")" stretchy="true">
                        <mrow>
                          <mfrac>
                             <mi>a</mi>
                             <mi>b</mi>
                          </mfrac>
                       </mrow>
                    </mfenced>
                 </mrow>
                 <mrow>
                    <mn>9999</mn>
                 </mrow>
              </msub>
           </mrow>
        </mrow>
     </mfenced>
  </mrow>
</math>

<math>
  <mrow>
     <mfenced open="(" close=")">
        <mrow>
           <mrow>
              <mn>99999</mn>
           </mrow>
           <mrow>
              <msub>
                 <mrow>
                    <mn>9999</mn>
                 </mrow>
                 <mrow>
                    <mfenced open="(" close=")" stretchy="true"><!-- Here stretch required -->
                        <mrow>
                          <mfrac>
                             <mi>a</mi>
                             <mi>b</mi>
                          </mfrac>
                       </mrow>
                    </mfenced>
                 </mrow>
              </msub>
           </mrow>
        </mrow>
     </mfenced>
  </mrow>
</math>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mfenced">

    <xsl:variable name="varFrac">
        <xsl:choose><!--to check only within MFENCED descendant is MFRAC -->
            <xsl:when test="descendant-or-self::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')]/*[not(preceding-sibling::*)]/descendant::mfrac">Yes1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="descendant-or-self::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')]/*[(preceding-sibling::*)]/descendant::mfrac">No1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="descendant-or-self::mfrac">Yes2</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <!-- to check MFRAC found as online (first child-descendant of msub). -->
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[name()='mfrac']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when  test="not(ancestor::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')])">Yes1a</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when  test="(ancestor-or-self::*/parent::*[not(preceding-sibling::*)]/parent::*[matches(name(), '^(msubsup|msub|msup|munder|munderover|mover|msqrt|mroot)$')])">Yes11a</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($varFrac, 'Yes')">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="stretchy">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

> If MFRAC found and which is not under MSUB, then attribute STRETCH
>   required for MFENCED.

```
<xsl:template match="mfenced[.//mfrac except .//msub//mfrac]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="stretchy">true</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

> If MFRAC found as descendant to MFENCED and under
>   FIRST-CHILD-DESCENDANT of MSUB, then STRETCH required.

```
<xsl:template match="mfenced[.//msub/*[1]//mfrac]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="stretchy">true</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

> In third MATH from input xml, 2nd MFENCED required STRETCH, even that
>   MFRAC descendant of 2nd child descendant of MSUB, but with within that
>   MFENCED, MFRAC is not having MSUB as its ancestor.

I'm sorry, I don't understand your English here.

Comment: sir, last point, 2nd MFRAC is descendant of sub's 2nd child. But within the MFENCED (within this MFENCE only) MFRAC is not having ancestor as MSUB, thats why I coded some generate-id() to check within that MFENCE. Please suggest.

Comment: soon I will get help of your code sir, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that in XSLT 2.0 you can rewrite `generate-id($X) = generate-id($Y)` as `$X is $Y` which simplifies things a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but still unable to stretch 3rd math's second MFENCED, plus one for your valuable suggestion.